# Trying to use freeze_graph.py results in FailedPreconditionError:

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

From my understanding, tensorflow's freeze_graph.py is supposed to support the new checkpoint format, and I should just be able to use something like

```
freeze_graph.py --input_saver ./checkpoints/model-49-295 --output_graph ./graph.pb --output_node_names "predictions:0"
```

Just to be clear,

```
ls ./checkpoints
checkpoint
model-49-295.data-00000-of-00001
model-49-295.index
model-49-295.meta
```

However, when I do this I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 255, in <module>
    app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 187, in main
    FLAGS.variable_names_blacklist)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 165, in freeze_graph
    input_graph_def = _parse_input_graph_proto(input_graph, input_binary)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 134, in _parse_input_graph_proto
    text_format.Merge(f.read(), input_graph_def)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 125, in read
    pywrap_tensorflow.ReadFromStream(self._read_buf, length, status))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: .
```

I am really confused by this, because `.` doesn't seem like a very helpful error code, and all of the references to FailedPreconditionError I can find have something like `FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value ...`

Anyone have any clue as to what's going on here?

Comment: I'm not sure , but i think you missed a _space_    **--input_saver./checkpoints/model-49-295**

Comment: Oops, not sure how that happened. The actual command I ran had the space (and I reran just now to be sure, same error).

I've updated the post to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code from freeze_graph.py I'm not really sure it does support the new format, or at least I can't figure out how it would, even though I've seen a number of places that claim it does. Anyway, my workaround for now was to write a simple script that does basically the same thing, but actually loads the checkpoint properly:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
from google.protobuf import text_format

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./checkpoints/model-49-295.meta', clear_devices=True)
    saver.restore(sess, './checkpoints/model-49-295')

    graph_def = sess.graph.as_graph_def()

    output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, graph_def, ['predictions'])

    with tf.gfile.GFile('./graph.pb', "wb") as f:
        f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

From the call stack, it looks like the parsing of the GraphDef .pb file is failing. The error message isn't very useful or informative though unfortunately!

My guess is that you need to pass in `--input_binary=true` as an argument, since by default it assumes the input graph is stored as a text protobuf.

Comment: That's the thing - there's no graphdef file, I have the output of saving the graph using a tf.train.Saver, which is a metagraph (.meta) file and the associated weigths (.data and .index). My suspicion is that freeze_graph.py just doesn't support freezing a metagraph as I don't see any code in freeze_graph.py to load a metagraph. This seems like a bit of an oversight given that it makes it annoying to use freeze_graph.py to freeze graphs produced by a saver.